# dojo query for multiple values with setQuery

Tags: dojo

I'm having trouble getting the syntax right for a `setQuery` method call for multiple values, i.e.

```
setQuery({x : 1}) or setQuery({x : 2})
```

combined. Or do I need to use filter?

Comment: It's confusing what you want. Do you want to set it to `or` operation of the two queries or doing `or` of their return values?

Comment: i'm trying to or the operation, so if x=1 or if x=2 it will match

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using [Dojo Store API](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store.html) I think one way to query using function is described [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/02/15/dojo-object-stores/)

You can modify it like this

```
store.query(function(item){
  return item.x == 1 || item.x == 2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on the store you are using.

In order to do that easier, you should use dojox.data.AndOrReadStore

[Dojo tool kit, and or read store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data/AndOrReadStore.html)

using that store you can use setQuery as:

yourgrid.setQuery({complexQuery:"x:1 OR x:2"});